# vuex actions edit context object

Tags: vuejs3, vuex

In the vuex actions we have a **context** object which contains `dispatch, commit, state, getters`

Can we modify this **context** object? maybe when we re creating vuex store? I want to replace the dispatch in context with my own version of **dispatch**

Comment: Please explain your intention more detailed. Why do you need to replace the `dispatch`. Some source code would be also very helpful.

Comment: I suppose you want to have some custom dispatcher for you actions. Why don't you write it as an action?

Comment: @Tolbxela I have very specific case and I'm filtering my actions depending on their names. Some actions are dispatched as is and some actions are modified. So I have replaced store.dispatch with my own function. But dispatch in context object is still original unmodified dispatch so I'm looking how to modify it also.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this not a variant?

```
  actions: {
    myCustomDispatch(context, myAction) {
        if (something) {
            context.store.dispatch(myAction);
        }
    }
  }
```